# Turn solid fill of image to outline

Tags: gimp

So for a wallpaper I'm making, I'm trying to edit this image so instead of a solid image like this, I am hoping to change this so it's just an 8-pixel outline. So the outside edges of the image is just an outline, with a width of 8 pixels. Is there a simple way to do this in a software like GIMP?

[image: fursona]

Answer (score 1):

Trace it in Inkscape:

[image]

Remove the fill color, insert a stroke which has the look you want:

[image]

You must experiment with the tracing settings to get the best possible result. Note that Inkscape makes a vector path which can be saved as SVG and used as a path in GIMP.

Note that half of the stroke width is outside the original shape area. You can fix it by making a half of the stroke width inset by inserting effect Path > Dynamic Offset. You can fix the effect by applying Path > Object to Path.

**ADD:** If you zoom in the tracing result before any edits you'll see that the edge goes through the edge pixels of the original bitmap shape, it doesn't go a zigzag along the pixel borders - no matter, if all cleaning and smoothing options are OFF and the tracing treshold has been lifted near white:

[image]

That's how tracing works. If you need the original pixelated edge you'll do better by staying in bitmap domain. In GIMP you should make a selection which contains the shape and shrink the selection that 8 pixels:

[image]

I selected the transparency by clicking it with the select by color tool, inverted the selection and applied Select > Shrink > 8 px.

Delete the interior by pressing DEL:

[image]

4500% zoom in shows that the result is as perfect as your original edge was:

[image]

To keep the sharpness the antialising was OFF in the tool options of Select by Color. Having it ON would make the edge smooth by inserting half transparent pixels.

Comment: I got Inkskape for Ubuntu 20.04, so I guess that will work. Is it possible to make the color the same one that's inside the image?

Comment: @AchakClaw Yes, you can change the stroke colour to anything you want. You can even colour a stroke with a gradient.

Answer (score 1):

With Gimp:

- `Layer > Transparency > Alpha to selection`
- `Select > To Path`
- `Select > None` (if you forget this, the outline will be half-width, and inside your current image)
- Hide the layer, add a new layer
- `Edit > Stroke path`, in `Stroke line` mode. You may want to explore Line styles, in particular the "Join" types (used `Miter` below)

[image]

PS: There is also a more direct `Edit > Stroke selection` but the results are usually poor.